# Office UI Fabric JS searchbox not retaining value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office-ui-fabric

We are using office UI fabric js SearchBox component on an aspx page.
We used the sample code from [here](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/SearchBox/SearchBox.html).
The issue that we are facing is when the searchbox looses it's focus the values typed in searchbox is getting cleared and it becomes empty.
Even the same happens in their documentation site.
Anyone observing this issue and any help on addressing this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Used following fix:
css:

```
 .ms-SearchBox-field {
    padding: 6px 3px 7px 10px;
}
```

js:

```
fabric.SearchBox.prototype._handleBlur = function (event) {
    var _this = this;
    if (!this._clearOnly) {
        this._searchBox.removeEventListener("keyup", this._boundEnableClose);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!_this._searchBox.contains(document.activeElement) && _this._searchBoxField.value == "") {
                _this._clearSearchBox();
                _this._collapseSearchBox();
                _this.setCollapsedListeners();
            }
        }, 10);
    }
    else {
        this._searchBoxField.focus();
    }
    this._clearOnly = false;
};
```